# Why does my Windows terminal not recognize pip?

Tags: python, module, pip

I have Python 3.10 and I am trying to install a python module but when I try to I get this:

pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

Comment: Try pip3 instead of pip. Python should include pip after Python 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your python path, usually `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python`. In there, you should find a folder, like `Python310`. Open that folder and then find the folder called `Scripts`. In cmd, use the command `cd C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python<version>\Scripts`. Then use pip normally. It should work.